# JLabel not appearing in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I made a JFrame with JTextField, JPanel and a button in which the user inputs a value and after clicking the button, it will generate multiple labels based on the users input, but the JLabel **doesnt appear**. am i doing it wrong?

[image]

this is the coding for the button.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String s = jTextField1.getText();
    int noSub = Integer.valueOf(s);
    addData(noSub);
}
```

and this is the method to add JLabel.

```
public void addData(int a){
    jPanel1.removeAll();
    int num = a;
    JLabel jLabel[] = new JLabel[num];

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        jLabel[i]=new JLabel();
        jLabel[i] = new JLabel("Label "+i);
        jPanel1.add(jLabel[i]);
        jPanel1.revalidate();
        jPanel1.repaint();
    }
    jPanel1.updateUI();
}
```

Comment: `jPanel1.updateUI();` isn't doing what you think it is.  What layout manager are you using on `JPanel`?  I'm betting it's a `null` or "absolute" layout (or even `GroupLayout`)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah its null. what should i change ?

Comment: [See these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50402564/why-my-jtables-setbounds-doesnt-work#comment87820812_50402564)

Comment: @DanialWafiy The would depend on your desired result

Comment: @MadProgrammer how about just displaying it ? as long as its there then its fine

Comment: Change the layout to something like `FlowLayout` (`jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());`)

Answer (score 0):

Made a simple working example here:

```
public class Sample extends JFrame{
    private JTextField inputField;
    private JPanel outputPanel;

    private Sample() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel form = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        inputField = new JTextField(3);
        JButton submitBtn = new JButton("Enter");
        form.add(inputField);
        form.add(submitBtn);
        mainPanel.add(form, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        outputPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.add(outputPanel);
        submitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = inputField.getText();
                int noSub = Integer.valueOf(text);
                addData(noSub);
            }

            void addData(int data){
                outputPanel.removeAll();
                JLabel jLabel[] = new JLabel[data];

                for(int i=0;i<data;i++){
                    jLabel[i] = new JLabel("Label "+i);
                    outputPanel.add(jLabel[i]);
                }
                outputPanel.revalidate();
                outputPanel.repaint();
                // No need to call outputPanel.updateUI()
            }
        });
        setSize(400,500);
        add(mainPanel);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sample();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd move the `revalidate` and `repaint` statements outside of the `for-loop`, they are expensive calls and best used as a batch update