# why my jTable's setBounds doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to using table.setBound but i think it doesn't work.

here is the code.

```
public GUI() {
        this.setSize(800, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("GUI");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        this.add(panel);
        String[] col = { "Name", "grade" };
        Object[][] cells = {{ "A", "B" }, { "C", "D" }, { "E", "F" }};
        JTable table = new JTable(cells, col);
        table.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 100);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        this.setVisible(true);
}
```

and here is the output

[image]

Comment: *"I'm trying to using table.setBound but i think it doesn't work."* - Don't.  Make better use of the available layout managers. Try using `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());` instead

Comment: *"why my jTable's setBounds doesn't work"* - because this is how the layout system works - it's not your responsibility to set the size/location, you make use of the layout managers to do in a platform independent manner

Comment: that will fill the frame with the table.

Comment: Can I set the position of the table in a specific location?

Comment: You'll want to put your JTable into a JScrollPane, and then the JScrollPane into whatever JPanel needs to display it, one using an appropriate layout manager. You will want to study the layout managers tutorial and practice using various managers to gain an understanding of how to use them.

Comment: You shouldn't absolutely position anything. It's a newbie fallacy that this is the easiest way to create GUI's -- it isn't. Again, learn the layouts.

Comment: *"Can I set the position of the table in a specific location?"* - Technically, yes, practically, you shouldn't.  Millions of developer hours have gone into the layout management API, which has been designed to provide a simply and practical solution to differences in rendering pipelines of "same" OS's, let along the issues involved in supporting different OS.  Better to spend your time learning how to use the layout management system - it will save you a lot of time and hassle in the long run

Comment: *"that will fill the frame with the table"* - then use a `GridBagLayout`, it all honour the preferred size of the `JScrollPane`. Use the properties of provided by `GridBagConstraints` or `EmptyBorder` to provide padding as needed